# Can spl_autoload be placed in another file?

Tags: php

I'm currently making my first website with PHP. Rather than writing autoload for each individual page, I wish to create one file with a general autoload ability.

Here is my `autoloadControl.php`:

```
// nullify any existing autoloads
spl_autoload_register(null,false);

//specify extensions that may be loaded
spl_autoload_extensions('.php. .class.php');

function regularLoader($className){
    $file = $className.'.php';
    include $file;
}

//register the loader function
spl_autoload_register('regularLoader');
```

Here is my `index.php` file:

```
require("header.php");
require("autoloadControl.php");

$dbConnection = new dbControl();
$row=$dbConnection->getLatestEntry();
```

Currently, the `$dbConnection = new dbControl()` gives me the following error:

> Fatal error: Class 'dbControl'

So my question is, is there a way to use autoload this way or must I place it at the top of every PHP file I write that uses another file?

Comment: You can have it in another file, that is perfectly ok because you require that file. The only important thing is that it is executed, and that is the case with your code. However you have a configuration problem. which filename has the class `dbControl` and in which directories are all these files placed?

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Answer (score 0):

Placing `spl_autoload` in an external file is both valid and a good practice for making your code more maintainable--change in one place what could be 10, 20, or more.

It appears that your `dbControl` class is not being provided in the code you provided.  Assuming you are including the class before referencing it, and the class works properly, then you should have no problem accomplishing this task.

```
require("header.php"); 
require("autoloadControl.php");  
$dbConnection = new dbControl(); // Where is this class located?
```

Here is an OOP approach for your `autoloadControl.php` file:

```
<?php

class Loader
{    
    public static function registerAutoload()
    {
        return spl_autoload_register(array(__CLASS__, 'includeClass'));
    }

    public static function unregisterAutoload()
    {
        return spl_autoload_unregister(array(__CLASS__, 'includeClass'));
    }

    public static function registerExtensions()
    {
        return spl_autoload_extensions('.php. .class.php'); 
    }

    public static function includeClass($class)
    {
        require(PATH . '/' . strtr($class, '_\\', '//') . '.php');
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: The first sentence of this answers the question (though not the problem the OP is having). The rest appears to be irrelevant.

Comment: In case anyone comes upon this answer, I would like to make clear my opinion that this "Loader" class is not OOP (no objects, or even inheritance/polymorphism, involved), and does not add anything to the code it is based on, since it replaces each line of code with a one-line function, which must still be called in a separate line of code.

Comment: If you wish to be more constructive then post a true example as you seem to infer. This site is to help someone think for themselves, not tell them this is the one and only way but you have to do it just like this.

Comment: I didn't post a counter-example because I think the questioner's code is already structured correctly. I can't see any benefit of wrapping the calls in the way you have. You could argue for a single function "initialise_autoloader" which wraps all the code, I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not related to where you are defining your callback, but how.

Using `spl_autoload_extensions('.php')` would achieve the same thing as your custom callback; you don't need both if your callback is as simple as this. Your comment is also wrong - calling `spl_autoload_register` with no arguments will not clear current callbacks, but it will register the default callback.

However, in your code, you have specified the argument to `spl_autoload_extensions` incorrectly - it should be a comma-separated list of extensions. So I think what you want is this:

```
// Tell default autoloader to look for class_name.php and class_name.class.php
spl_autoload_extensions('.php,.class.php')
// Register default autoloader
spl_autoload_register();
// READY!
```

The main difference this will make from your code is that the default autoloader will look for 'dbcontrol.php' (all lower-case) whereas yours will look for 'dbControl.php' (case as mentioned in PHP code). Either way, you certainly don't need both.

Comment: I figured out the problem. It was a simple mistake I kept overlooking. Thank you for all the help. I also switched to the OOP style afterwards. xD